# Linker error in g++ while trying to link to SDL_ttf shared object files

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, g++, dynamic-linking

I am trying to use the SDL_ttf development library in an Ubuntu environment. I started by downloading the dev libraries via: `sudo apt-get install libsdl-ttf2.0-dev`.
Next, I imported the header file in my code as so:

```
#include <SDL_ttf.h>
```

When I compile with the command:

```
g++ -g -I /usr/include/SDL Main.cpp -lSDL -lSDL_image -lSDL_ttf land.cpp PerlinNoise.cpp Util.cpp org.cpp Init.cpp `sdl-config --libs
```

I get the following output:

```
/tmp/ccpLKljA.o: In function `init()':
/home/zoo/Desktop/World-A/Util.cpp:39: undefined reference to `TTF_Init'
/home/zoo/Desktop/World-A/Util.cpp:42: undefined reference to `TTF_Quit'
/home/zoo/Desktop/World-A/Util.cpp:48: undefined reference to `TTF_OpenFont'
/home/zoo/Desktop/World-A/Util.cpp:52: undefined reference to `TTF_Quit'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I understand this is a linker error however I do not know what to do to fix it. I know that the -lSDL_ttf command is not doing anything because removing it does not change anything. I tried to reference the .so file however that didn't change the results. I did this reference via the command: -LlibSDL_ttf-2.0.so.0.6.3. I am able to view the .so file and it does contain the commands listed above.

Comment: I don't believe you need the -I /usr/include/SDL. And I'm assuming there's a finishing ` at the end that was just missed out. Perhaps try moving the sdl config before the files, rather than the end? When I compile I use `sdl-config --cflags` and when I link I use `sdl-config --libs`, perhaps try having both. Just some suggestions.

Comment: Tried out what you suggested. to no avail. I need the -I to reference the header files, Removing it cause it to not know the header files exist.

Comment: Curious, I don't need it (same library, Lubuntu), I think the `sdl-config --cflags` does the include directories for me. Ack, I don't know what's wrong. Try including to the search path wherever the SDL_ttf library is as a hack around is all I can think.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put land.cpp, and the rest of the CPP files, before the libraries on the command line.